# How can i display the div on loop

Tags: jquery, html

for instance i have a link id which is equal to news1 or news2 and so on! what happens is that if i hover my mouse on the link it displays its information like this

```
<div id="nc1">

<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Nulla venenatis rhoncus libero ac interdum. </td>
</tr>
<tr> <td colspan="2">is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the <br>readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
<br>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
 <br>distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', <br>making it look like 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" id="hide">Hide</a></td>
<td>Read More</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</div>
```

this is my script

```
$("#news1").hover(function(){
$("#nc1").fadeIn();
});
```

how can i loop this links without making them a function

```
    <td><a id="news1" href="#">Nulla venenatis rhoncus libero ac interdum.  </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Decemeber 09,2012</td>
<td><a id="news2" href="#">Proin gravida placerat nulla, euismod consectetur mauris tincidunt a. </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Decemeber 09,2012</td>
<td><a id="news3" href="#"> euismod consectetur mauris tincidunt a. </a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should accept some answers to your questions...

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
$("#news1").hover(function(){
     for (var i = 1; i < NumberOfDivs; i++){
         $("#nc"+i).fadeIn();
     }
});
```